# Webpack 5 Asset Modules not bundling images in

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, assets

I'm trying to use the new webpack 5 feature [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) to include a static png image in my react library. This **should** be a basic task but I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why the image is not being included. I've done the following things.

1. Included the rule as part of **webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: __dirname,
        assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[hash][ext][query]'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.png/,
            type: 'asset/resource'
          }
        ]
    },
};
```

2. Imported and used the image in a component

```
import React from 'react';
import image from '../src/assets/transport-belt-down.png'

function RenderedSquare(props: RenderedSquareProps){
    return <img src={image}>image</img>
}

export { RenderedSquare };
```

This component is the only thing rendered in index.ts, so the image is definitely being used.

However the image does **not** get included in the *dist* folder when I run `tsc`.
This means on consuming the library you get the following error .

```
../factorio-blueprint-renderer/src/assets/transport-belt-down.png
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

Things I have tried

- Use a jpg instead of a png
- Regress to file-loader and url-loader instead
- Manually include the assets folder in webpack.config.js
- Move the image to src
- Use require() instead of import
- Use relative / direct import
- Prayed to my various gods

Comment: Not sure how can you run `tsc` alone. You have to run `webpack` cli instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the value of 'assetModuleFilename' in output and 'rules' in module. It worked for me.

```
output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: __dirname,
    assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[name][ext]'
},
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
            type: 'asset/resource',
        },
    ]
}
```